# Putnam 2009 A4 clarification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, contest-math

Can anyone verify if this proof of the 2009 A4 Putnam problem is correct? Thanks!

2009 A4. Let $S$ be a set of rational numbers such that

I. $0 \in S$.

II. If $x \in S$, then $x \pm 1 \in S$.

III. If $x \in S$ and $x \not\in \{0,1\}$, then $1/(x(x - 1)) \in S$.

Must $S$ contain all rational numbers?

My strategy was to just take $S$ to be the minimal set satisfying the above conditions and show that $2/3 \not\in S$. I. and II. immediately imply that $\mathbb{Z} \subset S$. Now suppose $2/3 \in S$. Then by II. and III., there must exist some $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ (with $\gcd{(a,b)} = 1$) such that
$$\frac{1}{(a/b)(a/b - 1)} = \frac{3n + 2}{3},$$
for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Simplifying the left hand side, we get
$$\frac{b^2}{a^2 - ab} = \frac{3n + 2}{3}.$$
Let $d = \gcd{(b^2, a^2 - ab)}$. There exists some $h \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $h \mid d$ and $h \mid b$. Then $h \mid a^2 - ab$. Since $h \mid b$, we have $h \mid a^2$. But $\gcd{(a,b)} = 1$ and $h \mid b$, so $h \not\mid a$ unless $h = 1$, so $h = 1$. Therefore $d = 1$. Since $\gcd{(3n + 2, 3)} = 1$, we conclude that $b^2 = 3n + 2$ and $a^2 - ab = 3$. But $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$, so this is a contradiction. We conclude that $2/3 \not\in S$, so $S$ need not equal $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: _Rational integers_; is that just a pleonasm, or do you mean something else than integers? Furthermore - what is the question? What areyou trying to prove?

Comment: I think the poster means 'rational numbers' reading through the proof.  What's the actual question though?  Is it to describe $S$ or to show that $S \not= \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Whoops. Can't believe I forgot the actual question, haha. You're supposed to prove whether or not $S$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand where do these $a,b,n$ come from. Moreover, you should prove that such minimal $S$ exists (but maybe this is easy).

Comment: By minimal I meant don't assume anything is in $S$ except $0$, which must be in $S$ by I. Then see if it follows that $\mathbb{Q} \subset S$. II. and III. imply if $2/3 \in S$, then $2/3 = 1/(x(x - 1))$ for some $x \in S$ or $2/3 + n = 1/(x(x - 1))$ for some $x \in S$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $S \subset \mathbb{Q}$ we can write $x = a/b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: When you say _Then by II. and III._, aren't you actually using III. the other way around? i.e. given that $y\in S$, assuming there is an $z\in S$ such that $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=y$. So in your case $y=\frac{3n+2}{3}$ and $z=\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: Yeah because I'm only assuming that $0 \in S$. The question says asks if $S$ is some subset of the rationals with these properties, must $\mathbb{Q} \subset S$, so if the answer is no you can just only assume $0 \in S$ and find some rational that I.,II.,III. don't imply is in $S$. So in other words just take $S$ to be the minimal set implied by the three conditions.

Comment: To Litho's answer, I'd add that, if you're trying to show that some $p/q$ is not in the minimal set satisfying the three axioms, it may be clearer to show that the set $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{n+p/q \mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ satisfies the three axioms.  This is how Kedlaya and Ng's solution goes, with $p/q=2/5$.  It's exactly the same idea, but I think it is easier to make such a proof convincingly rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

> Since $\gcd{(3n + 2, 3)} = 1$  we conclude that $b^2=3n+2$ and
>   $a^2−ab=3$.

There is another possibility: $b^2=-(3n+2)$ and $a^2−ab=-3$. And these conditions can be satisfied, for example, with $a=1$, $b=4$ and $n=-6$. So this proof is incorrect.

Comment: Ah ok, great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!