# Putnam 2009 A4 : $S$ be a set of rational numbers such that if $x$ in $S$, then $x+1$ in $S$ and $x-1$ in $S$

Tags: contest-math, recursion

Question

$
\text{Let } S \text{ be a set of rational numbers such that}
$

\begin{align*}
(a) &\ 0 \in S; \\
(b) &\ \text{If } x \in S, \text{ then } x+1 \in S \text{ and } x-1 \in S; \text{ and} \\
(c) &\ \text{If } x \in S \text{ and } x \notin \{0, 1\}, \text{ then } \frac{1}{x(x - 1)} \in S.
\end{align*}

$
\text{Must } S \text{ contain all rational numbers?}
$

My attempt (answer) am I right?

Noww it's clear that $S$ contains $0$ due to property $(a)$.

Let consider property $(b)$. If $S$ contains $0$, then by applying $(b)$ repeatedly

$
0 \in S \Rightarrow (-1) = 0 - 1 \in S \Rightarrow (-2) = (-1) - 1 \in S \Rightarrow \ldots \Rightarrow 2 = 1 + 1 \in S \Rightarrow \ldots
$

Let consider property $(c)$. If $S$ contains an element $x$ which is not $0$ or $1$, then it also contains $\frac{1}{x(x - 1)}$, and by applying this property repeatedly, $S$ will contain a set of rational numbers of the form $\frac{1}{x(x - 1)}$, where $x$ is not $0$ or $1$.

Therefore, $S$ does not necessarily contain all rational numbers. It contains a specific subset of rational numbers based on the properties $(a)$, $(b)$, and $(c)$.

Comment: That is not a proof. You have to show that there is (at least one) rational number which is not contained in $S$. – Have a look at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h316669p1703559.

Comment: If you wish do prove this statement is wrong, you must find a counterexample. Plus if $\frac{1}{x (x-1)} \in S$, you have $\frac{1}{x (x-1)} + 1 = \frac{x^2-x+1}{x (x-1)} \in S$ so be careful

Comment: I didn't get your point?

Comment: The point is, after you've used (c), you still have to obey (b), which enlarges $S$ considerably. And then after that, you have to obey (c) again, and then (b) again, and then....

Comment: See earlier discussion of this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548382/putnam-2009-a4-clarification – also, if you have the points to see deleted questions, it came up at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765655/putnam-2009-a4-can-we-generate-bbb-q-from-bbb-z-via-operations-x-pm1

Comment: See also https://math.hawaii.edu/home/pdf/putnam/Putnam_2009.pdf

Comment: It is only impossible for $2/5$ or any other?

Comment: May be a useful (easier) exercise for you is to try and show that if rule (c) is replaced with: *If $x\in S$ and $x\neq0$ then $1/x\in S$*, it follows that actually $S=\Bbb{Q}$. How would your argument change if that were the actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that you haven't considered the interaction between rules (b) and (c) properly.

As you have correctly noted, $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S$ because all integers can be reached by starting at 0 and either adding or subtracting 1 repeatedly, per property (b).

Then by applying property (c) to the integers other than 0 and 1, we get that all of the following rational numbers are in $S$:

- $\frac{1}{2 \times 1}, \frac{1}{3 \times 2}, \frac{1}{4 \times 3}, \ldots$

But then all of *these* are *also* in $S$:

- $\frac{1}{2} \pm 1, \frac{1}{2} \pm 2, \frac{1}{2} \pm 3, \ldots$
- $\frac{1}{6} \pm 1, \frac{1}{6} \pm 2, \frac{1}{6} \pm 3, \ldots$
- $\frac{1}{12} \pm 1, \frac{1}{12} \pm 2, \frac{1}{12} \pm 3, \ldots$

Because we can apply rule (b) to all of the values we've confirmed are in $S$. And then we can apply rule (c) to all of *those*, and so on.

So in order to prove the statement one way or another, you have to do one of the following:

- Show that for any rational number $\frac{p}{q}$, there is a sequence of transformations corresponding to rules (b) and (c) that lets you reach it; or
- Show that there exists at least one rational number that strictly *cannot* be constructed through such transformations.

As the AoPS thread linked in the comments discusses, the set of reachable values relates to quadratic residues but proving it is not entirely trivial.